# Scroll to active link jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I having a quite hard time in doing this thing.
I have a landing page with 12 buttons on it. When you click a button, it directs you to a page with a nav bar with 12 li a's.
I already made a portion of the code that sets it to active.

```
<li><a href="..." class="active">
```

when that page with the active a class loads, it should scroll to it. the navbar is horizontal. i've tried scrollTo, but no joy. Thanks .

Update:
Here's the sample ss.

http://postimg.org/image/xtn1ljsnt/
the tab "Item 5" must be shown in the middle. It's like

Item4 Item5 Item6

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should include relevant HTML or a jsFiddle in your question.  It's imagine how your website looks like exactly.

Comment: i posted the sample image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard for me to visualize the markup If you only provide a single element, but the example below should be enough if you modifiy it to suit your scenario.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        #foo {
            margin-top: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">Hello</div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#foo").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arniekoz/m7rstc53/)